# How to Export the Code Coverage report of jtest outside of it to share the report with the team

Tags: java, code-coverage, jtest

Is there any way to export the Code Coverage percentage of the class files to some report format from the jtest tool so this report can be shared with the rest of the team?

Answer (score 0):

According to the [online docs](http://www.technology.heartland.edu/courses/Computer%20Science/Programming/Java%20Courses/JTest%20User%27s%20Guide/view_rep.htm) you can export them to HTML/XML and ASCII, you can even apply XSL to make your own formats.

Answer (score 0):

When the tests complete execution, find report generation button to create an html report of the results and coverage. Depending on license and versions of JTest you have, you may be able to customize more report style through the JTest preferences.